# Using sqlite confusing about null object reference

Tags: java, sqlite

Just to preface I've been linked to a thread on null pointer references and couldn't see how it helped for my situation it may just be because I started using java a month ago.. so sorry if this question is redundant. 
I'm receiving null object reference error to my function MYDBHandler.staffToString() which is being called in my class here.

```
public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner staffSpinner;
    MyDBHandler db;
    String staffNames = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        staffSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.staffSpinner);
        populateSpinner(db);
    }
public void populateSpinner(MyDBHandler db){
    staffNames = db.staffToString();
    List<String> Staff = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] parts = staffNames.split("/n");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String part3 = parts[2];
    String part4 = parts[3];
    String part5 = parts[4];
    Staff.add(part1);
    Staff.add(part2);
    Staff.add(part3);
    Staff.add(part4);
    Staff.add(part5);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<>(Order.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Staff);
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    staffSpinner.setAdapter(adp1);
}
```

}

Pointing to this function in my dbhandler class

```
 public String staffToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STAFF + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor point to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move back to first row
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("staffname")) !=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("staffname"));
                dbString += "/n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return dbString;

    }
```

if the problem isnt here I can post more but I'm currently stumped as my objects shouldnt be null?

Logcat is as follows

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.ben.assignmentpart2.MyDBHandler.staffToString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.ben.assignmentpart2.Order.populateSpinner(Order.java:25)
                                                                                   at com.example.ben.assignmentpart2.Order.onCreate(Order.java:21)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste the relevant lines of the error's stacktrace

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've never used a stacktrace before so I'll have to take the time to look it up ill post it when I'm able :)

Comment: Ok just realised that stacktrace is just logcats output never heard the term before x_x I've posted it up just now it seems to be pointing to the oncreate function